# UIDatePicker for week numbers

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I am new to iOS but I'm not new to programming.

I would like to make a `UIDatePicker` with one selection being the weeknumbers and the second selection being the year. So; is there any way to make the list display custom data? Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Any links to tutorials and such are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIDatePicker doesn't do that. Just make an ordinary UIPickerView and populate it as desired.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use "UIPickerView" . It has UIPickerViewDataSource UIPickerViewDelegate function  .you can custom data freedom.